# Can't Access DOM objects as Array's in Angular 5.1.1

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5.1.1 and getting errors when we attempt to access select DOM objects as indexes. We have tried accessing them as direct properties but that does not seem to work either. We assume this relates to some local setting or missed package. Can someone suggest a way to resolve this.

### Example 1:

```
window.document['locale'];
```

*Results in*

> Element 'Document' has no index signature.

### Example 2:

```
window.navigator['browserLanguage'];
```

*Results in*

> Element 'Navigator' has no index signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... To avoid this problem you need to change your `tsconfig.json` to include the following in the `CompilerOptions`

```
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors":  true
```